# Python, store results in a dict or similar

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm not sure if a dict is the best way to do this. If don't, I'd be glad if you guys could tell me the best way to do this.

I want to store `usernames`, and inside of this, I want to store a `list of objects`. For example.

```
 Name: 'Sophy',
    Lst: [ object1, object2, object3... ],
 Name: 'Osprey',
    Lst: [ object1, object2, object3... ],

 ....
```

Thing is, I'm not sure if a dict is what I'm looking for. and if so, I'm not sure how to make a dict to look like this. I also will need later to iterate through all objects of each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is very open ended, you can do a variety of thing like

- make it a dictionary with key the username and value the whatever list of yours

  ```
    data = {'Sophy':[ object1, object2, object3... ],
            'Osprey':[ object1, object2, object3... ],
             ...
             }
  ```
- a list of dictionaries

  ```
    data = [ {"Name": 'Sophy',  "Lst": [ object1, object2, object3... ]},
             {"Name": 'Osprey', "Lst": [ object1, object2, object3... ]},
            ...
            ]
  ```
- a class

  ```
    class User:
        def __init__(self,name, lst):
            self.name=name
            self.lst=lst

    data = [User('Sophy', [ object1, object2, object3... ]),
            User('Osprey', [ object1, object2, object3... ]),
            ...
           ]
  ```

among others things...

Comment: A class was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A list of tuples or dictionaries seems like the way to go.

Dictionary:

```
data = [{'Sophy': [ object1, object2, object3... ]}, {'Osprey': [ object1, object2, object3... ]}, ....]
```

To iterate over it:

```
for dict in data:
    name = dict.keys()
    for obj in dict.values():
        print(obj)
```

Tuple:

```
data = [('Sophy', [ object1, object2, object3... ]), ('Osprey', [ object1, object2, object3... ]), ....]
```

To iterate over it:

```
for i in data:
    name = i[0]
    for obj in i[1]:
        print(obj)
```

I think using tuples here makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at a `json`  format. Basically a nested dictionary.

Comment: JSON isn't relevant here, the OP hasn't mentioned anything about serialization

Comment: No? JSON is a text-based serialization format. It's simply not relevant here, the OP is asking which data structures to use, not what serialization format

Comment: Still. Using a ```json``` format, which I said, is a good way to go. For example, ```{"sophie" : {"lis" : [object1, object2, object3...]}, "osprey": {"lis" : [object1, object2, object3]}}```

Comment: I don't think you understand, JSON is a *serialization format*. It is a category error to say you should use JSON format here. What you've shown, for example, isn't even valid JSON, but it is valid Python. JSON is not a "nested dictionary" it is **text**

Comment: It's valid in python? so in other words I was right it is a good way to do it.

Comment: But it **isn't JSON**

Comment: I understand that, which is why I said json format. The example is the format a json file would follow.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dictionary.

```
>>> my_names = dict()
>>> my_names['sophy']=['object1', 'object2']
>>> my_names
{'sophy': ['object1', 'object2']}
```

Here 'object1' can be your object instead of a string.
To iterate you can do something like,

```
>>> for key,value in my_names.items():
...   print(f"{key} : {value}")
... 
sophy : ['object1', 'object2']
```